# Multiclass data redistribution

Tags: optimization, sampling

I want to redistribute the data in classes according to new proportions and wonder what is the optimal way to do it.
For example I have

`10 30 60 elements in each class a,b,c`

and apparently the fractions in each class are as follows:

```
0.1 0.3 0.6
```

What if I want to set the fractions as follows:

```
0.3 0.2 0.5
```

and to throw away the other data.
New data cannot be generated and the maximum number of data points should be kept.
Can it be generalized to a hundred of classes?

**UPD**:
I derived some minimization problem:

$$
min_\textbf{n} \; f(\textbf{n}) = - \sum p^{new}_i \log{\hat p_i} =  - \sum p^{new}_i \log{(\hat n_i/ \hat N)} 
$$

$$
  = \log(\hat N)- \sum p^{new}_i \log{(\hat n_i)} 
$$
s.t
$$\hat n_i \le n_i^c \; , \forall i \in 1:C$$
$$ \hat N = \sum_i \hat n_i $$

But I don't know how to fomulate the condition that $\hat n_i$ should be also maximized at the same time.

where $\hat n$ is a number of elements in the i-th class, that i'm looking for, $N$ is total number of elements and $C$ is a number of classes.
$p^{new}_i$ is a class partition. $n_i$ is an original number of elements in the given class

How to solve it?

Comment: a simple way is to: 1) remove one data from the most populated class and re-calculate the proportions. 2) go to step 1) untill the desired proportions are met (within some reasonable bounds)

Comment: there can be variations on the above algorithm, eg if a certain min number of data points should be in each class, then step 1) can go tothe next most populated class and so on..

Comment: Doesn't it take too long? My dataset size is of the order of $10^5$, the number of classes are under 10 but a few dozens should be treated as well

Comment: You can use Random Under Sampler??

Comment: You can remove more than one data item at the same step, if it is faster. There are many variations of that simple algorithm

Comment: thanks I'll try random under sampler and removing data bunches

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is a simple way to calculate this:

1. For each class calculate the ratio new proportion / old proportion:

- a: 0.3 / 0.1 = 3
- b: 0.2 / 0.3 = 0.67
- c: 0.5 / 0.6 = 0.83

2. The max of these ratios is the only one which matters because it defines the hard limit in number of instances. For example in this case class a needs 3 times more data, so the full sample has to be reduced by 3. Let's say you have 1000 instances:

- a keeps its 100 instances so the full size of the sample must be 100/0.3 = 333
- b has 0.2 * 333 = 67
- c has 0.5 * 333 = 166

(I didn't check that this works in every case)